# imagemagick generate image from slice

Tags: imagemagick

Please help me for writing command for ImageMagick. I need to generate a border, while having only the top piece of this border. Here is algoritm:

1. Take the piece height, generate canvas width = height*3 and height = height*3
2. Take the top piece into top center place.
3. Rotate piece for 90 degree three times and position it into center right, bottom and center left position.
4. Make a corners from each slice. I think it must long each slice, next calculate a triangle mask for cuttng the unneccessary edge, but then I'm afraid it will cover each other. So, I down know, what to do. Have any ideas?

Comment: Is this your algorithm or is it a quiz question?  As you sound unsure of the last step.

Comment: With the corners, do you mean the border image should be split between the two edges along the diagonal, looking like two triangular sections of the image?

Comment: Also: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border

Comment: This is exactly what I mean

Comment: In which case, the second question.

Answer (score 1):

I find your question quite hard to understand, but I gather you basically want to make an entire picture frame from a picture of one side of it - i.e. a picture of the frame moulding.

I realise it is a bit late, but fancied a little challenge, so here is a bash script that takes a picture of the top piece of moulding as a parameter and makes a frame from it...

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# pictureframe
# Mark Setchell
#
# Make a picture frame from a single horizontal moulding picture - with mitred
# corners and a transparent middle for a photo!
################################################################################
# Set DEBUG=1 for debugging info
DEBUG=1

# Image of the moulding is the 1st parameter, use "moulding.jpg" if none given
moulding=${1:-moulding.jpg}
[ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "DEBUG: Using file: $moulding"

# Get width and height of image
read w h < <(convert "$moulding" -format "%w %h" info: )
[ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "DEBUG: Dimensions: ${w}x${h}"

# Determine corner points of mitring mask - it looks like this
#
#     ----------------------------
#      \                        /
#        ----------------------
#
polyline=$(convert "$moulding" -format "0,0 %w,0 %[fx:w-h],%h %h,%h" info:)
[ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "DEBUG: Mitring mask: $polyline"

# Mitre corners
dbg=""
[ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && dbg="-write mask.png" && echo "DEBUG: Mask is in file mask.png"
convert "$moulding" \( +clone -evaluate set 0 -fill white -draw "polyline $polyline" -alpha off $dbg \) -compose copyopacity -composite top.png

# Build whole frame by rotating top through the angles and compositing onto extended blank canvas
convert top.png -background none -extent x${w}            \
    \( top.png -rotate 90  \) -gravity east  -composite   \
    \( top.png -rotate 180 \) -gravity south -composite   \
    \( top.png -rotate 270 \) -gravity west  -composite -flatten result.png

[ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "DEBUG: Output file is: result.png"
```

So, if I start with this moulding,

[image]

it will generate this:

[image]

And if I start with this

[image]

it will generate this:

[image]

Note that this script may not make the same aesthetic decisions as a professional picture framer :-)

But then again, it will never cut a badly fitting mitre :-)